# Writing Custom Action in Wix (Bundle)

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action, burn, wix3.7

I have a bundle of two MSIs where one of the MSI needs to copy files from disk(installer directory) to target. The custom action is written in C#. The Bundle builds fine and creates the exe. But When I try to install it, I get an error "0x80070643 - Fatal error during installation.". Looking at the logs, I see this error logs
    ...

```
>  [0640:13E0][TimeStamp]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
>  [0640:13E0][TimeStamp]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
>  [141C:0DD4][TimeStamp]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI     package.
...
```

And in my .wxs file for Sample2.msi, I have 
...

```
<Binary Id="CopyFilesAction" SourceFile="..\..\Release\MyCustomAction.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="CopyDiskFiles" BinaryKey="CopyFilesAction" DllEntry="CopyDiskFilesAction" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CopyDiskFiles" Before="InstallFinalize" />            
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

....

and the C# custom action looks like,

```
namespace MyCA
{
  public class TestApp
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CopyDiskFilesAction(Session session)
        {
            try
            {               
                string file = "Read me.txt";
                string sourceDir = session["SETUPEXEDIR"]; //SETUPEXEDIR      //SourceDir
                string installDir = session["INSTALLDIR"];

                if (File.Exists((Path.Combine(sourceDir, file))))
                {
                    File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, file),         Path.Combine(installDir, file), true);                 
                }               
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return ActionResult.Failure;
            }

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the whole trace logging:

```
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i001: Burn v3.7.1224.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path:     >D:\Source\ABC\BuildArtifacts\Installer\MyBundle.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.    >{5EF92470-E632-47DC-9E11-482A05E00748} {10DC3C00-CD2D-4475-A00C-90A9E3D8AE5D} 2796'
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallFolder' to value     >'[ProgramFilesFolder]ABCD\'
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallFolder2' to value     >'[WindowsVolume]ABCD\'
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value     >'C:\Users\USER1~1.EFG\AppData\Local\Temp\ABCDEF_20140218173420.log'
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value     >'D:\Source\ABC\BuildArtifacts\Installer\ABCDEF.exe'
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'ABCDEF'
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i101: Detected package: Sample2.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i101: Detected package: Setup, state: Absent, cached: None
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
>[14D0:329C][TS]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i200: Plan begin, 2 packages, action: Install
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_Sample2.msi' to     >value     >'C:\Users\USER1~1.EFG\AppData\Local\Temp\ABCDEF_20140218173420_0_Sample2.msi_rollback.log'
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_Sample2.msi' to value     >'C:\Users\USER1~1.EFG\AppData\Local\Temp\ABCDEF_20140218173420_0_Sample2.msi.log'
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_Setup' to value     >'C:\Users\USER1~1.EFG\AppData\Local\Temp\ABCDEF_20140218173420_1_Setup_rollback.log'
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_Setup' to value     >'C:\Users\USER1~1.EFG\AppData\Local\Temp\ABCDEF_20140218173420_1_Setup.log'
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i201: Planned package: Sample2.msi, state: Absent, default requested:     >Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache:     >No, dependency: Register
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i201: Planned package: Setup, state: Absent, default requested: Present,     >ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No,     >dependency: Register
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i300: Apply begin
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\USER1~1.EFG\AppData\Local\Temp\    >{GUID}\.be\ABCDEF.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{GUID}\ABCDEF.exe'
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {GUID}, version: 0.5.0.0
>[0AEC:026C][TS]i305: Verified acquired payload: Sample2.msi at path:     >C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Sample2.msi, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package     >Cache\{55B1CFF4-A620-4A93-957F-1FE72A5F12E0}v3.2.846.0\Sample2.msi.
>[0AEC:026C][TS]i305: Verified acquired payload: Setup at path: C:\ProgramData\Package     >Cache\.unverified\Setup, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\    >{GUID}v0.5.0.0\ABCDEF_Standalone.msi.
>[0AEC:026C][TS]i305: Verified acquired payload: f196699D08E79FB7EFC1A2D8AD29BD56F at     >path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\f196699D08E79FB7EFC1A2D8AD29BD56F, moving     >to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{GUID}v0.5.0.0\PFiles\ABCD\ABCDEF\ABCDEF Text1.txt.
>[0AEC:026C][TS]i305: Verified acquired payload: fE9DE1A6A8366231950181982D4565C1E at     >path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\fE9DE1A6A8366231950181982D4565C1E, moving     >to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{GUID}v0.5.0.0\PFiles\ABCD\ABCDEF\ABCDEF Text2.txt.
>[0AEC:026C][TS]i305: Verified acquired payload: f2F54C7BEFF6CBBBD79154610C4108101 at     >path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\f2F54C7BEFF6CBBBD79154610C4108101, moving     >to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{GUID}v0.5.0.0\PFiles\ABCD\ABCDEF\ABCDEF Text3.txt.
>[0AEC:026C][TS]i305: Verified acquired payload: fED2A2B9E0F5E346B4A4FD28554B8E6D9 at     >path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\fED2A2B9E0F5E346B4A4FD28554B8E6D9, moving     >to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{GUID}v0.5.0.0\PFiles\ABCD\ABCDEF\ABCDEF Text4.txt.
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {55B1CFF4-A620-4A93-957F-    >1FE72A5F12E0}, version: 3.2.846.0, package: Sample2.msi
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i301: Applying execute package: Sample2.msi, action: Install, path:     >C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{55B1CFF4-A620-4A93-957F-1FE72A5F12E0}v3.2.846.0\Sample2.msi,     >arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i319: Applied execute package: Sample2.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i325: Registering dependency: {GUID} on package provider: {55B1CFF4-    >A620-4A93-957F-1FE72A5F12E0}, package: Sample2.msi
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {GUID}, version: 0.5.0.0,     >package: Setup
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i301: Applying execute package: Setup, action: Install, path:     >C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{GUID}v0.5.0.0\ABCDEF_Standalone.msi, arguments: '     >ALLUSERS="1" ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files     >(x86)\ABCD\\ABCDEF" ABCD_DATA_DIRS="C:\ABCD\"'
>[0AEC:0980][TS]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
>[0AEC:0980][TS]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
>[14D0:0E78][TS]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i319: Applied execute package: Setup, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
>[14D0:0E78][TS]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i318: Skipped rollback of package: Setup, action: Uninstall, already:     >Absent
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i319: Applied rollback package: Setup, result: 0x0, restart: None
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {GUID}, package: Setup
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i351: Removing cached package: Setup, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package     >Cache\{GUID}v0.5.0.0\
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i326: Removed dependency: {GUID} on package provider: {55B1CFF4-A620-    >4A93-957F-1FE72A5F12E0}, package Sample2.msi
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i301: Applying rollback package: Sample2.msi, action: Uninstall, path:     >C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{55B1CFF4-A620-4A93-957F-1FE72A5F12E0}v3.2.846.0\Sample2.msi,     >arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i319: Applied rollback package: Sample2.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {55B1CFF4-A620-4A93-957F-    >1FE72A5F12E0}, package: Sample2.msi
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i351: Removing cached package: Sample2.msi, from path:     >C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{55B1CFF4-A620-4A93-957F-1FE72A5F12E0}v3.2.846.0\
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {GUID}
>[0AEC:0980][TS]i352: Removing cached bundle: {GUID}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package     >Cache\{GUID}\
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested     >restart:  No
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x643    
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: EulaAcceptCheckbox = 1
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: InstallFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\ABCD\
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: InstallFolder2 = C:\ABCD\
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WindowsVolume = C:\    
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 4
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog =     >C:\Users\USER1~1.EFG\AppData\Local\Temp\ABCDEF_20140218173420.log
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_Sample2.msi =     >C:\Users\USER1~1.EFG\AppData\Local\Temp\ABCDEF_20140218173420_0_Sample2.msi.log
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_Setup =     >C:\Users\USER1~1.EFG\AppData\Local\Temp\ABCDEF_20140218173420_1_Setup.log
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = ABCD
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = ABCDEF
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource =     >D:\Source\ABC\BuildArtifacts\Installer\ABCDEF.exe
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {GUID}
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_Sample2.msi =     >C:\Users\USER1~1.EFG\AppData\Local\Temp\ABCDEF_20140218173420_0_Sample2.msi_rollback.log
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_Setup =     >C:\Users\USER1~1.EFG\AppData\Local\Temp\ABCDEF_20140218173420_1_Setup_rollback.log    
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 0.5.0.0
>[14D0:0E78][TS]i007: Exit code: 0x643, restarting: No
```

Am I missing something? Thank you in advance for your comments!

Comment: Does the destination folder exist? Does the installer have the necessary privilege to copy to the folder. Can you put some trace logging in to see where the failure occurs and what the exception message is?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @acarlon Yes, destination folder exists and installer has the privilege to copy the folder. If I comment out the CustomAction from the InstallExecuteSequence, everything works fine. I have tried running the Bundle installer, "As an Admin"(though I am still an Admin on the machine), switch on/off the "ForcePerMachine" falg, turned off UAC but none of them don't seem to resolve it.

Comment: Hey OP, did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue right now.